# using _get to get the id from hidden input and to insert it into the database

Tags: php, mysql

i use modal for validation [image: image here]

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
              <div class="form-group margin-top-20">
                <p><strong>Do you want to join this group?</strong></p>
              </div>                 
        </div><br>

          <button type="button" name="join" id = "join" class="btn btn-black">Join</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-black" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                                 <?php

                                $db = new Group($conn);
                                 $gid = '';
                                 if(isset($_POST['join'])){
                                    if ( !empty($_GET['gr_id'])) {
                                          $gid = $_GET['gr_id'];

                                  $inserted = $db->insertgroup($session_id, $gid);
                              ?>
                                 <script>
                                   window.location = '../views/groups.php';
                                 </script> 
                                <?php
                                 }
                                }
                                ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

using this script im getting the id of a certain group and insert it into my db but it seems that the gid is not getting fetch so what happens is that when i tried to click the join button

```
<script>
window.location = '../views/groups.php';
</script>
```

this script supposed to run but did not..

im getting the ID from here:

```
        <?php 
    $res = $db->g_viewlist();
    $gid ='';
    foreach ($res as $key => $value){
    $gid = $value['g_id'];

    ?>      
    <div class="col-lg-12" align="center" style="border:1.5px solid #59960b;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;">

    <button class="btn2 btn-2"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" style="padding: 2px 2px; margin-left:50%"><strong> Join</strong></button>
<input id="gr_id" type="hidden" name="gr_id" value="<?php echo $gid ?>">               
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

the gid is from outside the modal form.. is there a way to fetch the id for me to be able to insert it into my db?.

Comment: You should have written gr_id(hidden field ) in the modal body where you had write join button .Then can be use a form .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method of doing is wrong. You cannot get the gr_id value using `$_GET` method and `$_POST`.. one more you are posting any form in modal therefore `$_POST` will not work.

Calling Modal HTML :

```
 <button class="btn2 btn-2 join"  data-id="<?php echo $value['g_id']; ?>" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" style="padding: 2px 2px;
 margin-left:50%"><strong> Join</strong></button>
```

I have added new class 'join' and added a attribute 'data-id'.

Revise your modal structure code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="joinModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Do you want to join this group?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" name="join" id = "join" class="btn btn-black" onclick="joinGroup()">Join</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-black" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="join_id" id="join_id">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added `<input type="hidden" name="join_id" id="join_id">` and `onclick="joinGroup()"` to store the join_id value and save it the database respectively.

Using javascript click function, you can assign the data-id value to input hidden field of modal box. After that when someone clicks on JOIN button ajax will trigger and save the data into database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.join').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#join_id').val(id);
});

function joinGroup(){
    var join_id = $('#join_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"insertvalue.php",  // ajax call to insert data
        data: 'join_id=' + join_id,
        success:function(data) {
          window.open('your url','_self'); 
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: i edited my post so you can get a better understanding where the gid is coming from.

Comment: you haven't read the answer properly.... You method of doing is wrong. You cannot get the gr_id value using $_GET method and $_POST. Do you have a better understanding of how $_GET and $_POST works ?